# WindowsForm app with wpf windows is not working on other computers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm new to WPF and c# programming,
i have built a winform app with a database and some wpf forms.wpf forms contain some background images and componentone tab controls.
To add wpf forms:
i added a wpf user control and modified its code as a window.in that case i m unable to put background images from user directories.
i mean

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="\Images\carcar.jpg" />
```

this doesn't work

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="G:\Management System\Management System\Images\carcar.jpg" />
```

this works

And i can't run my app on any other computer(i pasted Debug folder).
how to run my application on another computer which does not have coponentone studio/& visual studio installed.

Comment: `carcar.jpg` is added as a resource file in your project? If yes is it in same assembly as your WPF usercontrol and what's its hierarchy like?

Comment: it was not, now it works fine except the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Build Action for your images to `Resource`; this will embed them for WPF to consume.

To distribute your application, make sure you've set all non-standard dependencies to Copy Local.

Comment: it worked thank you very much for helping. but now i have another problem the application is not retrieving data from the database. i have a service-based database, how to automatically get connection string changed?